# How can I get my session right, after successfully log in to my website

Tags: php, session

Every time i try to log in to my website it should show me a message that you are logged in but it's not happening. It keeps on showing a message that im logged out but my taskbar gives me a message that my login success.

I've tried everything but it does'nt work :(

This is my header.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        echo '<form action="Connectingdatabase/includes/logout.mrk.php" method="post">
                <button type="Submit" name="logout-submit">Log out</button>
            </form>';
        }
    else {
    echo '<form action="../includes/login.mrk.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/E-mail">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="Submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
          </form>';
```

This is my index.php

```
<?php
 require "header.php";
?>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    echo '<p>You are logged in!</p>';
}
else {
    echo '<p>You are logged Out!</p>';
}
?>
```

This is my login.php

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false) {
            header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=wrongpwd");
            exit();     
            }
            else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                session_start();
                $_SERVER['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                $_SERVER['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?login=success");
            exit();
            }
            else {
            header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=wrongpwd");
            exit();
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../systemlogintut/index1.php?error=nouser");
            exit();
```

My expected result it. If my log in success it will not show the log in form, and it should be sending me a message that im logged in and gives me only the log out button on my nav bar

Comment: Which file is which in your question?

Comment: The 2nd one @Phil

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You have three code snippets in your question; which snippet belongs to which file?

Comment: Your login-code is incomplete. Do you start the session there? How do you execute the query?

Comment: Try dumping the value of $_SESSION and check whether userId is set

Comment: @Qirel I just cut it. Yes I start it when the password is correct `else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                session_start();
                $_SERVER['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                $_SERVER['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];`

Comment: @poga you don't seem to be setting the $_SESSION['userId'] value anywhere. Change the $_SERVER['userId'] to $_SESSION['userId'] after the session_start()

Comment: Yeah, in login.php you are using $_SERVER instead of $_SESSION

Comment: Thanks Guys! Now its running fine. I just replace it with $_SESSION. Thanks bro